# how to print 2 alerts consecutives WinJS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, winjs, windows-8.1

I want to print two alerts on my app, one to show an application and after pressing close button on first alert to show the second alert

```
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello Welcome").showAsync();
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Welcome to my app").showAsync();
```

if I just print an alert, everything works good but on the other scenary (two alerts) the code stops with an error, how to fix that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple `MessageDialog`s open at the same time. Since the `showAsync` returns immediately ([async reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh464924)), your code needs to wait until it's closed.

To do that you'd need to rely on the `Promise` returned by `showAsync`:

```
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello Welcome")
    .showAsync().done(function() {
         Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Welcome to my app").showAsync()
    });
```

Above, the code waits for the `done` callback to be called on the `Promise` and then shows a second dialog.